# Not able to print a ajax success function data

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin that consist a form with Ajax Functionality.

I am able to see the json array as below in **console** tab while debugging.

Note: **Error Function** in Ajax Call displays below result:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "[{"id":"1","school_name":"Apollo Beach Elementary …lo Beach","rating":"A","type":"Elementary"}]Array", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Here is the **Ajax Code**

```
function ajaxformschool() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxschoolajax.ajaxurl,
            data: {'action':'ajaxschool_process'},
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data[0]);         
        },
     error:function(exception){console.log(exception);}
        });

}
```

Html link where the function is called

```
echo '<a onclick="ajaxformschool();" style="cursor: pointer"><b>Search</b></a>';
```

**Ajax Action Function**

```
    function ajaxschool_process() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM schools;");

    echo json_encode($data);
    die($data);
}
```

Comment: What's the response's `statusCode`?

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass `$data` in `die()` function :

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM schools;");
echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

die() tries to print the value passed in parameter, then prints "Array", so jQuery can't parse the JSON data since it's not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass any parameter with `die()`

```
function ajaxschool_process() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM schools;");

    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it....

**Ajax Code**

```
function ajaxformschool() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxschoolajax.ajaxurl,
            data: {'action':'ajaxschool_process'},
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                var result=eval(data);
                alert(result.id);       
        },
     error:function(exception){console.log(exception);}
        });
```

**Ajax Action Function**

```
function ajaxschool_process() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM schools");

    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
```